# Java ProGuard can't find referenced class

Tags: java, proguard

I'm trying to obfuscate my java code with ProGuard (as suggested on stackoverflow).

However I'm getting "cant find referenced class" errors

[image: error]

Below is my configuration, I didn't change anything from default really. Just added input and output jars.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/cc081c27450468b9dee89c069fd535dc.png]

I've searched on the internet for solutions for a while and many suggested -ignorewarnings or -keepclass ..... 
But none of them seem to work.

Hopefully someone can help me :)
I prefer using the GUI if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java8 runtime references some additional classes that are not present in `rt.jar` but in `plugin.jar`. It is safe to ignore these warnings, so you can specify the following option in your configuration:

```
-dontwarn netscape.javascript.*
```

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/fc39d12efbad2c4fada086d053a5a714.png Now it gets stuck on this, after a while an output jar appears however it is non functional.

Comment: You can add -verbose to get more output, ProGuard is probably optimizing your application which can take a while.

Comment: Thanks, I waited alot longer this time. It finished but the jar is still broken. https://i.gyazo.com/1e5cac626d48c57fe26d17652ebff0ac.png . Any idea why?

Comment: What does broken mean? You probably have to keep some entry points in your application or other parts that are accessed via reflection.

Comment: The application is a game client and it's only loading half way on startup. It does load a .txt file on startup which is in the bin folder.

Comment: Alright I tried disabling every option except obfuscation in the hope that it would make the problem smaller. However now im getting JNI error.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a separate question, as the original one has been solved afaict?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116173/discussion-between-sjacobs-and-t-neidhart).